# jexcel - Get Page Number of a Cell or Row

Tags: java, excel, xls, jxl

I must implement an export excel function. The exported excel file must have a row to calculate sum at the end of each page (sum of row in that page).

Given a cell or row, anyone knows how to get the page number that cell or row is in?

I mean pages in a sheet. For example you have 10 pages in a sheet, separated by page break. Get the page number from a random cell or row (1 -> 10).

My only way of doing this now is to get the page size (paper size) and calculate base on every row's size to determine if a row is in a particular page.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  When you say "page" do you mean worksheet (Sheet in the lib)?  If you're writing data out into Sheets (you said exporting an excel file) won't you always know what Sheet you're currently writing to?

Comment: If you mean printed page.... well, a printed page can mean lots of different things depending on paper size, orientation and the scaling factor.  The only meaningful criteria you might use would be a fixed number of rows, in which case the coding is trivial.

Comment: @JimGarrison the row can differ in size too :( anyway, do you know how to get height and width of, for example: PaperSize.A4

Comment: No, that would depend on the margins specified and any scaling factor being applied at print time.

Comment: @NguyenTuanLinh thanks for updating. I'm not familiar with dealing with printed pages in jexcel sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: If I fix paper size, scaling and margin, is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can get close, but it will not match the results if somebody else opens the spreadsheet and prints it.  Can you explain why this is such an inflexible requirement?

Comment: I was given an example excel file. When I open that, it already in page break preview mode, and for each page, it has a last row that calculate the sum of every row above it (for that page only). So I think it is means to printed. And with each row, there is a description with different length, which I will have to expand the cell height to display each of them properly. I think my best bet, as your suggestion, is to fix the number of rows. With the paper size, I may get the max number of rows it can fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
    sheet.getSettings().getPrintArea().getBottomRight();
```

You get the cell that is on bottom right border of page. Just call getRow() or getColumn() and you get int.

For testing you can also set this for faster preview:

```
    sheet.getSettings().setPrintGridLines(true);
```